# how to step in newton method when the hessian is singular

Tags: pytorch, newtons-method, singular

I am trying to implement basic newton method using pytorch.
This is my code basically

```
hessian_inverse = torch.inverse(hessian)
step = -(hessian_inverse @ gradient)
new_point = curr_point + step
```

however, what should I do when the hessian is singular?
I tried to run my code but I got this error

> The diagonal element 1 is zero, the inversion could not be completed because the input matrix is singular.

Which tells me the hessian couldn't be inverted. How does newton method handle this in practice?